# Looking for a TVS

Tags: tvs

I am looking for a TVS like this one: https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Wurth-Elektronik/824541121?qs=16w8nSHsg3sizcsDurViDA%3D%3D

with operating voltage: 12 V
clamping voltage 19,9 V

However this one is assembled via SMD. I would need one to be assembed through hole, but I can't find one..

Can anyone recommend one?

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/tvs-varistors-movs/141?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGGABxwDsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9CYOHUQgUkDDgLEyIAAzNJIALQAmOQv4BXFSUjkArFu0w5AgCZc9YCozadIIAKpCB7AHlUAFlcdGxjPlwQQnYAT1Zor3CUcXEgA

Answer (score 1):

It's not very hard to find one with a very similar specification.

[Littelfuse 1.5KE15CA](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/tvs-diodes/leaded/1_5ke.aspx) is close enough. DO-201 package, bidirectional TVS 1500W, Vbr min=14.3, Vc=21.2. Widely available from multiple suppliers.